# Permanent failure when sending mail using mailgun

Tags: laravel, email, mailgun

I have a mailgun account I use to send mails on my site (domain.com) when someone signup, I then created another site on my subdomain (subdomainname.domain.com). However when I try to send mail from the subdomain site (subdomainname.domain.com) I get a permanent failure log in my mailgun account, and the email is not delivered. Please how can I solve this issue ? The mails sent from the main domain (domain.com)  is delivered successfully. 
The errors I get are :

02:13 PM    Failed: postmaster@mg.agroexpresslink.com → ewomaukah@outlook.com 'Witskids:Activate Your Account' Server response: 550 550 5.7.0 (COL004-MC2F27) Unfortunately, messages from (209.61.151.224) on behalf of (yahoo.com) could not be delivered due to domain owner policy restrictions.

01/26/17 08:00 AM   Failed: postmaster@mg.agroexpresslink.com → ewomaukah@gmail.com 'Witskids:Activate Your Account' Server response: 550 550 5.7.1 Unauthenticated email from yahoo.com is not accepted due to domain's 5.7.1 DMARC policy. Please contact the administrator of yahoo.com domain if 5.7.1 this was a legitimate mail. Please visit 5.7.1 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2451690 to learn about the 5.7.1 DMARC initiative. d72si348434oic.133 - gsmtp

01/25/17 02:02 PM   Failed: postmaster@mg.agroexpresslink.com → ewomaukah@yahoo.com 'Witskids:Activate Your Account' Server response: 554 554 5.7.9 Message not accepted for policy reasons. See https://help.yahoo.com/kb/postmaster/SLN7253.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem,  I changed the sender email from 'ewomaukah@yahoo.com' :

```
    \Mail::send($view ,$data,function($message) use($user, $subject, $email){
              $message->from('ewomaukah@yahoo.com','witskids');
              $message->to($email, $user->firstname );
              $message->subject( $subject);
        });
```

To my domain :

```
  \Mail::send($view ,$data,function($message) use($user, $subject, $email){
              $message->from('noreply@agroexpresslink.com','witskids');
              $message->to($email, $user->firstname );
              $message->subject( $subject);
        });
```